# How do you combine data from a column that only exists in another table?

Tags: mysql, sql, postgresql

I have two tables `Users` and `Reputation`.

`users` table:

```sql
  id            name              sites         intsize     extsize
-------   ------------------   ------------    ----------  ---------
  1             Ryan             phish.com        10           60
  2            Janice            test.com         20           50
  3             Tori             yahoo.com        30           40
  4             John             phish.com        40           30
  5             Brett            facebook.com     50           20
  6             Henry            google.com       60           10
```

`reputation` table:

```sql
 score          sites          
-------      ------------   
  10           phish.com          
  25           test.com        
  87           yahoo.com  
  85          facebook.com        
  87           google.com    
  12           badsite.net   
  3            g00gl3.xyz
```

I want to return all the `name`, the sum of the `intsize` and `extsize` columns from the `users` table as well as the associated `score` column from my `reputation` table that is associated with my `sites` column such that this is my result:

```sql
   name        sites          score         total size
----------  ------------   ------------   --------------
   Ryan      phish.com          10             70
  Janice     test.com           25             70
   Tori      yahoo.com          87             70
   John      phish.com          10             70
  Brett     facebook.com        85             70
  Henry      google.com         87             70
```

Would the query be:

```sql
SELECT sitecount.name, sitecount.sites, sitecount.sum, reputation.score 
FROM (SELECT name, site, SUM(intsize+extsize) FROM users GROUP BY sites) 
AS sitecount, reputation AS reputation
WHERE sitecount.sites = reputation.sites
```

Or should my query include a join? From research it seems like I can use `left join` (https://www.w3schools.com/sql/sql_join.asp) since I am only trying to return the all the sites that exists in my `users` table?

Comment: Tip of today: Always use modern, explicit `JOIN` syntax! Easier to write (without errors), easier to read an maintain, and easier to convert to outer join if needed!

Comment: Seems like there are missing tables. I can't understand how users and reputation are related.

Comment: @jarlh I am trying to map the user's sites to the respective score from the `reputation` table.

Comment: Your query will not work. The inner select may not group by sites. Which name must be selected for phish.com in the inner select ?

Comment: @Conffusion will my query work if I drop the `GROUP BY` clause? I am just trying to map the sites with the associated score from the `reputation` table and display the associated users and total count in the process. My table has multiple users with the same sites.

Comment: See https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/333952/why-should-i-provide-a-minimal-reproducible-example-for-a-very-simple-sql-query

Comment: In your output you want a line for each user record so no need to group. Yes, I think it will work if you remove the group by. You need to fix your outer select too as it returns country and misses score. Better look at the solution of @Fahmi and use `JOIN` instead. Much easier to read and modify and you give more freedom to the database driver to optimize the query.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use join

```
select name, u.sites, score,intsize+extsize as totalsize
from users u join reputation r on u.sites=r.sites
```